# How to use defined Laravel remote connections in Envoy

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Laravel has a really nice remote SSH connection configuration file: `app/config/remote.php` (see: http://laravel.com/docs/ssh). It integrates well with the `SSH` class and things like `./artisan tail`, and generally makes it easy to work with SSH connections from within a Laravel application.

It also now has [Envoy](http://laravel.com/docs/ssh#envoy-task-runner) to make it easy to define complex tasks to run on remote systems via SSH, for deployment etc. It's similar to the `SSH` class, only you use the blade syntax to easily define commands, rather than having to build a manual artisan command.

However Envoy seems to be a completely manual config independent of the Laravel configuration file. This means you need to configure hostnames, and paths, in two different places.

Is there a nice way to load the Laravel remote config into the Envoy file, so there is a single source for the information?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the `Config` class to get your configuration values out of `remote.php`.

For example, to get your production connection, it would be as easy as `$connection = Config::get('remote.connections.production');`.

Comment: I'm not near a computer to test, but will Envoy automatically pick up the Laravel config or do I need to require some files and a bootstrap?

Comment: I think you may need to `@include('vendor/autoload.php');`